# unable to reboot after rescue mode by bitdefender

Tags: windows-8, boot, anti-virus, malware

I am using windows 8 and bit defender total security.
I recently went into rescue mode using bitdefender then I selected to reboot my computer. There is a black screen with text "reboot: Machine restart" but nothing has happened for around 8 minutes. I want to hold the off button down and shut the computer down but I am worried that it will corrupt the hard drive and all essential files that deal with making the computer work.
Are there any suggestion on the actions that I should take?

Comment: a problem of loading system files may be caused this, If you can boot with some boot utility soft-wares, and check your hard drive for bad-sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Try running check disk (CHKDSK) when your computer restarts. If that doesn't work, try running a disk clean up.

**CHKDSK:** http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-scan-fix-hard-drives-with-chkdsk-in-windows-8/

**Disk Cleanup:** http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/delete-files-using-disk-cleanup#delete-files-using-disk-cleanup=windows-8